# spring-boot-actuator-docs overrides spring-boot-rest-docs output

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, spring-restdocs

I'm using `spring-boot-rest-docs` to produce API documentation and I'd like to link from that documentation to the docs provided by `spring-boot-actuator-docs` to complete my service's available endpoint documentation.

The problem is that when I include the recommended runtime dependency on `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-docs` it overwrites my `/docs/index.html` runtime endpoint with the actuator documentation.

Is it possible to configure the actuator documentation to appear at a different URI so that I can hyperlink to it from my own service's asciidoc document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[application.properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/)**

```
endpoints.docs.path=/docs
```

Comment: good old spring, there had to be a property in there somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Change the docs Id

endpoints.docs.id=your-new-id